# How to find class of interface at run time in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I have a bunch of classes and a particular instance is declared as an interface... how do I find out within eclipse what the superclass/class is?

```
MyInterface john;
john = StaticBuilder.person; // returning some instance that is MyInterface
```

The code is much more complicated but I wish there was a way to find out what class john is when I use Eclipse ctrl+click it obviously just brings me to the interface and when I go deeper and deeper I find myself in a circle through dozens of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the actual class is shown in the [variables view](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-debug_view.htm):

[image]

or just evaluate `john.getClass()` in the [Display view](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-14.htm?resultof=%22%64%65%62%75%67%22%20%22%65%76%61%6C%75%61%74%65%22%20%22%65%76%61%6C%75%22%20) after you put and stopped at a breakpoint at `john = ...`.

[image]